# Tor on Chromebook/Chrome OS

Tags: chrome-os

Google's Chrome OS runs on Chromebooks built by different manufacturers. Various applications can be installed via the Chrome store but there's no straightforward way to install Tor.

How could one set up Tor to run on a Chromebook or any device running Chrome OS?

<sub><sup>(I'm not looking to just proxy Chrome through another Tor'd device like [this page suggests](http://www.omgchrome.com/an-introduction-to-tor-on-chrome-os/), even though it is a decent idea.)</sup></sub>

Comment: Have you considered something like tails?  Can the device boot a USB?

Comment: https://deepankar.io/kronymous looks like (the beginnings of) a port of Chrome to NaCL. I haven't tried it.

Comment: how does this makes sense? You are monitored by Google

Comment: @FyodorGlebov one could argue the same about Windows. There are plenty of threat models where the local network or government are of more concern than Google/Microsoft.

Answer (score 4):

Currently it seems like the only options involve either using a proxy on an external device as you listed, or rooting and dual-booting a linux distro (eg chrubuntu) on the chromebook.

Answer (score 3):

Now with linux apps on chromebooks you can do the following to run the tor browser:

- [Enable Linux app](https://www.howtogeek.com/363331/how-to-set-up-and-use-linux-apps-on-chrome-os/)
- Run the following commands

  - `sudo printf "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main contrib" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch-backports.list`
  - `sudo apt update`
  - `sudo apt install torbrowser-launcher -t stretch-backports`
  - `torbrowser-launcher`

Steps based on [this wiki entry](https://wiki.debian.org/TorBrowser).

This is not the same as full blown tor for the whole os but its a start.

Answer (score 0):

first install

Source Package  **firefox-esr**
Install Howto
Update the package index:

## sudo apt-get update

Install firefox-esr deb package:

## sudo apt-get install firefox-esr

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

https://sourceforge.net/projects/tor-browser-ports/files/8.5-arm64/

https://sourceforge.net/p/tor-browser-ports/activity/?page=0&limit=100#6205fab2bc223d958469ca51

**TorBrowser auf ARM CHROMEBOOK installieren**

download:

https://master.dl.sourceforge.net/project/tor-browser-ports/8.5.6-arm64/tor-browser-linux-arm64-8.5.6_de.tar.xz?viasf=1

or

https://altushost-swe.dl.sourceforge.net/project/tor-browser-ports/11.0.6-alsa/tor-browser-linux-arm64-11.0.6_de.tar.xz

entpacken:

tar xf tor-browser-linux-arm64-8.5.6_de.tar.xz

---

### kolo.bezka@penguin:~$ cd Downloads
kolo.bezka@penguin:~/Downloads$ cd tor-browser_de
kolo.bezka@penguin:~/Downloads/tor-browser_de$ ./start-tor-browser.desktop

Launching './Browser/start-tor-browser --detach'...
kolo.bezka@penguin:~/Downloads/tor-browser_de$

starten mit Terminal
./start-tor-browser.desktop

schaut dann so

https://i.ibb.co/ZM3mYwD/CHROMEBOOK-Screenshot-2022-02-14-21-04-34.png

https://i.ibb.co/X3BFC5R/ARM-CORTEX-8cores.png